# Qual a utilidade da keyword auto em C?

Tags: c, escopo-de-variáveis, palavras-reservadas

A *keyword* `auto`, definida pela linguagem C, é uma *keyword* antiga e aparentemente sem utilidade na linguagem. Sei que em C sua função é definir que ela deve ser armazenada na *stack* como uma variável local cuja vida acaba com o fim do escopo em que foi declarada. Sei também o que ela faz em C++, embora isto não venha ao caso.

Essa *keyword* é realmente necessária e tem alguma utilidade real para a linguagem. Parece-me inútil, já que todas as variáveis de escopo de C são armazenadas na *stack*, e somente através do uso de funções específicas é possível fazer uso do heap.

Lembro-me de ter lido alguma coisa a respeito de macros que pode tornar a *keyword* auto necessária, mas não sei se isso realmente tem algo a ver com minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A palavra-chave `auto` foi incluída na linguagem C porque ela era a palavra-chave para declarar variáveis locais na antecessora de C, a [linguagem B](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.html) — e sim, estou falando sério. Como B não tinha tipos, uma definição de uma variável precisava ser precedida ou de `auto` ou de `extrn` (equivalente ao `extern` de C).

Como no princípio de C havia a necessidade de portar uma quantidade de código B para C, a palavra-chave `auto` foi incluída para reduzir a carga de trabalho desses portadores (outra característica era a possibilidade de especificar funções sem um tipo de retorno, como por exemplo `main() { /* ... */ }` e fazer com que elas retornassem `int` implicitamente).

Answer (score 5):

Nenhuma.

Ok, tecnicamente ela indica onde a variável será armazenada, assim como `static` e `extern` pode ser usadas. Só que ela só pode ser usada dentro de função. E se não usar nada dentro da função a variável declarada será local, que é o mesmo que o `auto` indica. Então sua utilidade prática é nula.

De fato em macro pode ser útil para evitar que a variável seja declarada como `static`, mas se você criar uma variável em uma macro, talvez esteja abusando do recurso.

Se quiser manter compatibilidade do código com C++11 para cima, então não use. C++11 especificou outro uso para esta palavra-chave permitindo a inferência de tipo.

Ou seja, sua avaliação está correta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Nenhuma? Nem mesmo em versões mais antigas da linguagem? Será que ela foi incluída na linguagem para uso futuro? Isso explicaria a falta de utilidade em versões anteriores a C++11, não?

Comment: Não lembro bem. Acho que tinha razão para indicar para o compilador colocar aquilo no registrador se ele achasse adequado, ao contrário de `register` que obrigava fazer isso. Hoje todo compilador toma essa decisão por conta própria sem precisar especificar nada, e mesmo especificando é ignorado.